# How to export a partial notebook in zim-wiki command line?

Tags: zim

Zim documentation specifies the following arguments for export at https://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Commandline_Options.html , but I am trying to find a command line equivalent of selecting a Page: and exporting single page with its subpages in the GUI like so:

[image].

In this screenshot PUBLIC is one of the pages in my notebook, and I can't tell how to specify exporting only that page and its subpages on the command line export after trying various variations of   --root-url and  --index-page (with semicolon and without).

What I see instead is that every time entire notebook is being exported. The -r argument makes it sound like it's possible, but I can't quite figure out the syntax.

I am using most recent windows installer of ZIM.

Answer (score 0):

#### I am trying to find a command line equivalent of selecting a Page: and exporting single page with its subpages

There is an example in the documentation:

> Exporting from the commandline
>
> Try something like:
>
> ```
> $ zim --export --output=./html --format=html --template=./foo.html ~/Notes
> ```

You can use a similar command, adding the `-r` option and replacing `Notes` with the path to `PUBLIC`.

Source [Zim - a desktop wiki](https://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Export.html)

Comment: I've been passing the root of the notebook, without realizing that I can try what you suggest. Unfortunately if I pass the subfolder for the page I want to export (%NOTEBOOK_ROOT%\PUBLIC), without the -r flag - it exports entire notebook still (it must be going up the tree, finding the .zim file to indicate root of notebook and deciding to export from here.) With the -r flag, it exports nothing ...

Comment: FWIW, I ended up copying the .zim file prior to export to each directory that I want to export as a workaround, but that does not feel like the right way as that is not required when exporting subfolder from the UI.